# Guake terminal startup shell script

Tags: shell, terminal

I'm trying to create a startup script to open two tabs in Guake, execute commands, and then rename the tabs. Unfortunately the tabs are not being renamed. Also irritating, it's opening up the terminal in the directory of the shell script instead of the default ~/ directory. After reading the help file, I'm pretty sure that the script is correct.

Help file:

```
Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -f, --fullscreen      Put Guake in fullscreen mode
  -t, --toggle-visibility
                        Toggles the visibility of the terminal window
  -p, --preferences     Shows Guake preference window
  -a, --about           Shows Guake's about info
  -n NEW_TAB, --new-tab=NEW_TAB
                        Add a new tab
  -s SELECT_TAB, --select-tab=SELECT_TAB
                        Select a tab
  -g, --selected-tab    Return the selectd tab index.
  -e COMMAND, --execute-command=COMMAND
                        Execute an arbitrary command in the selected tab.
  -r RENAME_TAB, --rename-tab=RENAME_TAB
                        Rename the selected tab.
  -q, --quit            Says to Guake go away =(
```

And here is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# guakeStartup.sh

# open tabs
guake -e "irssi" -r "irssi"
guake -n -e "cd" -r "terminal"
```

Comment: Does adding `-s` to the lines help? Does splitting `-r` into its own execution (probably with `-s`) help?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe so. I've made the script but it only opens up one tab, peforms the first function, and doesn't do anything else (including renaming the first tab.)

`#!/bin/sh
# guakeStartup.sh

# open tabs
guake -e "irssi"
guake -s 0 -r "irssi"
guake -n "terminal"
guake -s 1 -e "cd"
guake -s 1 -r "terminal"`

Comment: Do the other lines of the script run? If you stick `echo` lines in there do you see the output? Can you run a series of commands like that from your shell manually and get it to work?

Comment: Yes, I can execute the commands by themselves and they work properly. I do not see the echo outputs, however.

Comment: Does the script finish or does it hang?

Comment: The only command the script executes is the -e "irssi". Everything after this is basically ignored.

Comment: But that works in your terminal correctly and doesn't hang or does that drop you into guake when run manually? When you exit irssi does the rest of the script execute? Can you run that in the background?

Comment: Etan,

I'm going to reply to this ASAP but I have to go to a site. WIll continue this and let you know as soon as I can.

Answer (score 5):

Try it like this inside your startup script:

```
guake --rename-tab="irssi" --execute-command="irssi" &
sleep 1 &&
guake --new-tab=2 --rename-tab="terminal" --execute-command="cd" &
```

Or more like your original:

```
guake -e "irssi" -r "irssi" &
sleep 1 &&
guake -n=2 -e "cd" -r "terminal" &
```